# Is it possible to refactor this scala code

Tags: scala, refactoring

I've got the following function:

```
def firstFunctionMethod(contextTypeName: String): Parser[FunctionCallExpr] = namespace into {
    namespaceName =>
      function into {
        functionName =>
          functionExprParameters(contextTypeName) ~ opt(secondFunctionMethod(getFunctionReturnType(functionName).get)) ^^ {
            case args ~ subPath => FunctionCallExpr(namespaceName + functionName, args, subPath)
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem that possible target class has 10 functions with exactly the same code. The only changes is that **firstFunctionMethod** and **secondFunctionMethod** is always different

Is it possisble to refactor it?

Comment: Types of these functions are dIfferent too?

Answer (score 0):

Next or similar code should work for you.

```html
  def firstFunctionMethod(contextTypeName: String): Parser[FunctionCallExpr] = firstFuncTemplate(contextTypeName, secondFunctionMethod)
  def firstFuncTemplate(contextTypeName: String, secFunc: TypeIn => TypeOut): Parser[FunctionCallExpr] = namespace into {
    namespaceName =>
      function into {
        functionName =>
          functionExprParameters(contextTypeName) ~ opt(secFunc(getFunctionReturnType(functionName).get)) ^^ {
            case args ~ subPath => FunctionCallExpr(namespaceName + functionName, args, subPath)
          }
      }
  }
```